# PHP CRUD - Adding dynamically file inputs

Tags: php, jquery

I know how to upload files, well, the basics. And it worked so far.
However, I need to make now a dynamic input fields in my crud system.

Basically, I have a **index.php, add.php, update.php** and **delete.php**, where I add User data like name, age, email etc etc. After those basic information, I have input file fields like profile image, driving licence etc. The crud operations work fine like that. 
Among these file inputs, there are two distinct section of files, one is "**registration**" and the other is "**checkout**"

In an ideal case, I need only one file input per user for registration and checkout, but, in the last time I was forced to add more, for example,

```
<input type="file" name="registration-1">
<input type="file" name="registration-2">
<input type="file" name="registration-3">
```

What I want on add.php page is, if I upload a file for registration input, that, dynamically, another input field with the name registration-2 (or something like that) appears beneath that, and so on i++ manners. This is my problem that I can't solve. I know it requires jquery, but i just don't know how to deal with saving it to database and updating, deleting this kind of inputs.

Comment: I would suggest an array instead of numbered names: `name="registration[]"`

Comment: Or allow a single file input to select multiple files using the `multiple` attribute

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when I retrieve those files from the database, they should have they respective input fields in the read view, like reg-1, reg-2 etc.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, @AbraCadaver has your solution